# Efficient way to get part of a string

Tags: c#

I have a name which is made of a `prefix` a `type` and name , i want to retrieve the `name` part.

`Prefix` always remains same but `Type` can change.

I have the following code to get the name part:

```
            string prefix = "Prefix-";
            string str =prefix + "Type-hello-j---.xml"; 
            str = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
            str = str.Substring(prefix.Length);
            str = str.Substring(str.IndexOf('-') + 1);
```

In the above example the name part is: `hello-j---`
Is there any efficient/better way to do the same in C# ?

Comment: Does Prefix always have - to separate it from type?

Comment: BTW, you should really consider using more descriptive variable names and *not* reusing variables. It will make your code much more readable.

Comment: @svick I agree with you in writing descriptive names but I reused the same for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [overload of `string.Split()` that lets you specify the number of parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx):

```
string fileName = "Prefix-Type-hello-j---.xml"; 
string withoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
var parts = str.Split(new[]{'-'}, 3);
string name = parts[2];
```

Comment: About to post the same thing +1

Comment: Is this actually more efficient than the OP's version? After all, this requires the allocation and population of an extra array that wasn't present in the original version.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think it doesn't matter. This code is not likely to be the bottleneck. I think both versions will be fast enough.

Comment: @svick: I don't think it will matter, either, but the OP explicitly asked for a version that is "more efficient/better", so it should at least be noted which of the two it is. My suspicion is yours is a tad "better" (in terms of readability), but probably less efficient. On an insignificant scale.

Answer (score 2):

If this is always the structure of your string, this would work :

```
string name =  str.Split(new[]{'-'})[2];
```

I'm assuming you only want "hello". If you want the rest of the name you could use the overloaded method as @KingCronus suggested :

```
string name = str.Split(new[]{'-'}, 3)[2];
```

Comment: Ah, just what I was typing for an answer.

Comment: That won't work correctly. The desired output is `hello-j---`, but your code will return just `hello`.

Comment: Beside the problem mentioned by svick, is this just shorter in LoC, or actually more efficient? After all, this version allocates an fills an extra array that was not required in the OP's version.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Its very clear that the OP is looking for a shorter way of solving the problem.

Comment: @AbZy: Sorry, but the question explicitly says "efficient". Read the question again if you missed it so far.

Comment: O.R Mapper instead of critiquing everyone's answers, perhaps you could provide a more efficient answer.. otherwise I would suggest be a little more constructive in your comments and less destructive

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an extension function that works like String.IndexOf but that gets the position of the nth occurrence of the specified character:

```
public static int IndexOfWithCount(this string input, char character, int occurenceNumber)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int numCaracter = 0; numCaracter < input.Length; numCaracter++)
        if (input[numCaracter] == character)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == occurenceNumber)
                return numCaracter;
        }

    return -1;
}
```

To use it:

```
string nameWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(str);
string result = nameWithoutExt.Substring(nameWithoutExt.IndexOfWithCount('-', 2) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you define efficient but if lines of code fits your defintion how about:

```
var str = "prefix-Type-hello-j---.xml"; 
var name = Regex.Match(str, @"(.+?-)(.+?-)(?<name>.+)\.").Groups["name"].Value;
```

The first two capturing groups consume the prefix and the the type then the namedgroup consumes the name until the extension starts.

This code assumes there is always a match, if there is not it will throw a nullreference exception.

See [Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx)